# How to check if specific values of Object items in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My goal: I want to modify this Array (See; Current Array with Objects) to only main properties where one or more (items) is greater than 0. In this example, the current Array should be modified by removing all object named: tags and sale_status from the Array, since there are no items is higher than 0 with count. So you only keep the Object over quotation_status.

How can I handle this the right way? I've tried various ways of looping, but can't figure it out.

**Current Array with Objects**

```
[{
    "id": "tags",
    "label": "Tags",
    "items": [{
        "key": 2,
        "count": 0
    }, {
        "key": 1,
        "count": 0
    }, {
        "key": 3,
        "count": 0
    }]
}, {
    "id": "sale_status",
    "label": "Status",
    "items": [{
        "key": "completed",
        "count": 0
    }, {
        "key": "processing",
        "count": 0
    }, {
        "key": "on-hold",
        "count": 0
    }]
}, {
    "id": "quotation_status",
    "label": "Status",
    "items": [{
        "key": "concept",
        "count": 1
    }]
}]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[{
    "id": "quotation_status",
    "label": "Status",
    "items": [{
        "key": "concept",
        "count": 1
    }]
}]
```

**Current Script**

```
function activeFilters() {
  let test = test1.value
  let filters = store.getters[test].filters

  const result = filters.filter((o) => o.items.some((obj) => obj.count));
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to get the desired result

```
arr.filter((o) => o.items.some((obj) => obj.count))
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "tags",
    label: "Tags",
    items: [
      {
        key: 2,
        count: 0,
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        count: 0,
      },
      {
        key: 3,
        count: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "sale_status",
    label: "Status",
    items: [
      {
        key: "completed",
        count: 0,
      },
      {
        key: "processing",
        count: 0,
      },
      {
        key: "on-hold",
        count: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "quotation_status",
    label: "Status",
    items: [
      {
        key: "concept",
        count: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = arr.filter((o) => o.items.some((obj) => obj.count));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. The only thing I get in console is: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

Comment: Add your full code, without code it is hard to tell what is the issue

Comment: I added the function script. For your information; The result works. I only get this wierd error.. It refers to `const result = filters.filter((o) => o.items.some((obj) => obj.count));` specific `filter`

Comment: FYI: Error itself is telling you the problem, There is no method `filter` on `undefined`. I mean when you are calling `filter` on an object then that object at that particular time is `undefined`.

Comment: BTW you are filtering the result in `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. I added a: If (filter) { } :)